# Delphi Text Edit Control with background colour

Tags: delphi, controls, lazarus, freepascal

Does Delphi (or even Lazarus with Free Pascal) have a control that displays text and allows you to set the background colour of each individual character?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this can be done in FreePascal, but in Delphi on Windows, `TRichEdit` can be coerced into displaying per-character background colors by using the Win32 [`EM_SETCHARFORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774230.aspx) message directly, with a [`CHARFORMAT2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787883.aspx) record.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply Remy, when i get time i will look into that... i have had a quick look at the controls that come with Lazarus and one called TsynEdit looks like a possibility... If anyone else has any info on suitable controls then please post... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.

See [TRichMemo](http://wiki.freepascal.org/RichMemo). Moreover in comparison with the `TRichEdit` in Delphi it has an advantage - it is cross-platform.
Also consider [this question and my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215188/how-to-prevent-trichmemo-from-resetting-text-attributes-when-you-add-new-text/47229438#47229438). They might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although it looks like I'll switch to C++ rather than Delphi.