# How to prevent TRichMemo from resetting text attributes when you add new text

Tags: user-interface, lazarus, richtext

I have a `TRichMemo` object which I create and populate with text at runtime.

I have a timer that triggers a function each 10 seconds. The function looks something like this:

```
procedure TServerSideForm.NewLineTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  timeForward: TDateTime;

  timerText: wideString;

  startRange, endRange: longInt;
begin
  timeForward := Time;
  timeForward := IncSecond(timeForward, ServerSideForm.NewLineTimer.Interval div 1000);

  //...

  timerText := TimeToStr(Time) + ' - ' + TimeToStr(timeForward);   


  startRange := Length(WindowMemo.Text);

  WindowMemo.Text := WindowMemo.Text + sLineBreak + sLineBreak + timerText + sLineBreak + sLineBreak;

  endRange := Length(WindowMemo.Text) - 1;


  WindowMemo.SetRangeColor(startRange, endRange, clGreen);

  //...
end;
```

Everything works perfectly, text in the desired range becomes green.

But as soon as I add some new text to my `TRichMemo`, everything resets back to black text.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to prevent this reset from happening?

P.S Same situation happens, when I use the `SetRangeParams` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Append` method instead of accessing a `type String` value `Text` as it keeps only the literals not the format.

Change

```
WindowMemo.Text := WindowMemo.Text + sLineBreak + sLineBreak + timerText + sLineBreak + sLineBreak;
```

with

```
WindowMemo.Append(sLineBreak + sLineBreak + timerText + sLineBreak + sLineBreak);
```

**METHOD 2**

Should you decide to add text withot line breaks you can replace the mentioned line with

```
uses RichMemoUtils;
...    
InsertColorStyledText(WindowMemo,timerText,Random($FFFFFF),[],Length(WindowMemo.Text) -1);
```

Comment: problem with append is that internally it simple does this: `Lines.Add(text)` and therefore adds an additional linebreak, which I don't want, because in other functions I am simply adding a single character to the text.

Comment: @lilbroomstick I appended the answer on your reply.